# .htaccess redirects too many times

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have written a .htaccess for the subdomain but it redirects too many times.

my complete code looks like

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain/$1 [R,L]
    
RewriteEngine On      

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^404/?$ /404.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^ http://subdomain/404 [L,R]
```

Comment: what do you want to?

Comment: Getting this error from this htaccess code:

This page isn’t working
URL redirected you too many times.

Answer (score 1):

The issue most likely is the topmost redirection. It implements a redirection loop. Also it is unclear what it is actually meant to achieve ... What is "subdomain" here? A hostname / subdomain name? So something like `http://sub.example.com/$1`?

Assuming that all "sub domains" you served by the same http server you'd need to add an additional condition to break that look:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{HOST_NAME} !^sub\.example\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

That could also be simplified to this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{HOST_NAME} !^sub\.example\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^ http://sub.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Also consider using the encrypted https protocol, it actually is the standard these days.

Comment: The loop is not breaking in subdomain

Comment: Please give a previcse explanation what URL you want to rewrite to what with that rule. Currently it is unclear what you are actually trying to do ...

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain/$1 [R,L]
> ```

You've not actually stated what you are trying to do. However, the only reason to check the `SERVER_PORT` for port `80` like this is if you are redirecting to HTTPS (port 443). But you are redirecting to HTTP (port 80) - so this will naturally result in a redirect loop.

You need to change `http` to `https` in the *substitution* string. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule (.*) https://subdomain/$1 [R=301,L]
```

(Ultimately, this should be a 301 *permanent* redirect, once you have confirmed it works as intended.)

OR, remove these directives entirely if you are not intending to force HTTPS (but you should be).

---

> ```
> RewriteRule ^ http://subdomain/404 [L,R]
> ```

And change to `https` in the last rule. (However, you shouldn't be redirecting to a "404" *error document* to begin with.)